# How to calculate monthly increase?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

if i have the data like this:
[RAWDATA and INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUxfp.jpg)

how could I do that?

Create a table of all Month 11 and Month 12, then JOIN them together to form a new table? 
What if there are 12 months rather than 2 months sales for each store, then I have to create 12 tables, which is ineffective.

**So is there an efficient way to calculate the increase compared with former month?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `join`.  Assuming that the month column is consecutive:

```
select t.*, tprev.sales,
       100 * ((t.sales / tprev.sales) - 1) as increase
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.store = tprev.store and t.month = tprev.month + 1;
```